# What does "do" mean in "They really do exist"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, syntactic-analysis, emphasis

I was watching an animation last night then I heard a sentence which was strange for me.
One of the characters sayed this sentence

> "They really do exist"

He sayed it because he saw a creature that he thought they don't exist , so my question is *what does **do** mean here??*

Comment: Although **this** question is about the present tense, the emphasising nature of the addition of *do* is well explained in other questions.

Comment: "to do" is not only auxiliary for questions and negations, it is also auxiliary for emphasis.  http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode119/languagepoint.shtml